# jquery mobile: keeping horizontal control group in one row

Tags: jquery-mobile, knockout.js

I have two dynamic horizontal control groups of radio buttons:

```
<div class="categories-panel" id="sections-panel">
    <fieldset id="section-choice-fieldset" data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
        <!-- ko foreach: Sections -->
        <input type="radio"
               data-mini="true" 
               ...
            />
        <label data-bind="text:Name, attr:{'for':Id}"></label>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

The content of controlgroups is updated by knockoutjs. The markup is updated this way:

```
self.refreshCategoriesList = function() {
    $("#section-choice-fieldset").find("input[type='radio']").checkboxradio();
    $("#category-choice-fieldset").controlgroup();
};
```

The problem is: the controlgroups don't fit in one row until I turn of and turn on the `display: inline-block` property of `.ui-controlgroup-controls` div in debugger:

before `display: inline-block` refresh:
http://i890.photobucket.com/albums/ac105/cubius/screen-1.png

after `display: inline-block` refresh (desired view):
http://i890.photobucket.com/albums/ac105/cubius/screen-2.jpg

How to make jQM always paint my controlgroups in one row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the way you select your control group is wrong in this line :

```
$("#category-choice-fieldset").controlgroup();
```

Mustnt it be

```
$("#section-choice-fieldset").controlgroup();
```

(Maybe a typo)
You could do this in any of the two ways :

### Method 1

Works fine in my fiddle. I'd say you move the `<script>` tag from head to body because `page` events of jQM dont play well with KnockOut.js and KnockOut.js needs a DOM ready to work properly, AND DOM `ready` doesnt work well with jQM. So I guess its a vicious loop indeed.

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/k7UR5/

### Method 2

And you could try one more thing in your `refreshCategoriesList` method:

```
//$("#section-choice-fieldset").find("input[type='radio']").checkboxradio();
//$("#category-choice-fieldset").controlgroup();
$("[data-role=page]").trigger("create");
```

Refreshing the entire controls on the page - thats what `trigger("create")` does

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/k7UR5/1/

Answer (score 0):

If you are updating the control group (appending, modifying etc) , access the control group like this:

```
$("#my-controlgroup").controlgroup("container")["append"]($el);
```

You need to access the control group `container`. See my jsfiddle for modifying the control group:

http://jsfiddle.net/androdify/WAzs6/